# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 while running OpenCV example program

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv3.0, surf

I've been trying to compile and build a openCV example program located in here "https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d6f/tutorial_feature_flann_matcher.html".

I've followed this series of tutorial to install OpenCV in mac "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U49CVY8yOxw"

I tried to print the OpenCV version `std::cout << "openCV Version : " << CV_VERSION << std::endl;` and its prints correctly which means OpenCV has been installed correctly.

But when i run the above example code i get Undefined Symbols error

[image]

Can someone help me on this...